# Unable to connect to website PHP

Tags: android

My code keeps getting Exception: Request Aborted. It does not connect to the php for me to run my code.

I uses HttpClient to execute the httppost and uses a responsehandler to obtain the JSONArray from the database. However, i would need to connect alot of times(more than 10 times)using a for loop as i need alot data from the database.

```
12-20 12:22:49.757: W/SingleClientConnManager(10370): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
12-20 12:22:49.757: W/SingleClientConnManager(10370): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
12-20 12:22:49.827: I/System.out(10370): Exception : Request aborted


String[] obtainFavShare(String id){
        final String id1 = id;
        final String[] favShare = new String[2];
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
    public void run() {
                try {
                        try{                 
                            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                            httppost= new HttpPost("http://115.29.148.5//favshare.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
                            //add your data
                            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", id1));
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                            //Execute HTTP Post Request
                            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                            //Parse
                             JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                             JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                             favShare[0]= json.getString("favourite");
                             favShare[1]= json.getString("share");
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
        return favShare; 
    }
```

MY PHP CODE

```
 <?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="Eyeche";
$username_localhost ="Peopeo";
$password_localhost ="****************";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

$ID = $_POST['ID'];

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$sql = "SELECT favourite, share FROM `wp_posts` WHERE ID = 'ID'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $output[] = $row;
}
print(json_encode($output));


?>
```

Comment: Did you check your the status of your web server (Apache or whatever)? Ensure that all services are running.

Comment: did you add permission in your manifestfile?

Comment: You have to use Asynctask for this types of web related call. see <a href="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html">AsyncTask</a> for more details

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your *`link`*. when I run the url it is simply throwing null. that's why you are getting exception. First try to fiz that issue and run in the device.

Comment: its running null because it selects stuff based on the id i post up. I shall post the PHP up for clarity

Comment: I check ur code. there is no problem. I got response from ur site also. one thing is the response is dynamic then try to parse the response in effective way